# Passing sensitive headers in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I am migrating my application from Zuul to Spring Cloud Gateway. How can I replace the sensitive header part of below code in Spring Cloud Gateway?

```yaml
zuul:
  routes:
    tableau:
      path:/test/**
      sensitiveHeaders:
      url: https://example.com
      stripPrefix: false
```